# What's the proper way to use a variable with spaces in part of a shell script command?

Tags: bash, command-line, rhel, subversion, variable-substitution

How can I include spaces as part of a variable used in an svn command for RHEL bash scripting? Or if there's something else wrong with the following, please advise.

The SVN URL variable has no spaces, and this section is working:

```
svn checkout $svnUrl $checkoutDir --username $username --password $password --non-interactive --depth immediates --no-auth-cache
```

But the SVN update command that works when hard coded is not working as a variable:

```
updateSubProject="&& svn update --set-depth infinity --no-auth-cache --username $username --password $password --non-interactive"
cd project-dir $updateSubProject
cd ../another-project $updateSubProject
```

Comment: Relevant reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better would be to make a function to do it like

```
updateSubProject() {
    pushd "$1"
    svn checkout "$svnUrl" "$checkoutDir" --username "$username" --password "$password" --non-interactive --depth immediates --no-auth-cache
    popd
}

updateSubProject project-dir
updateSubProject path/to/another-project
```

this way you aren't trying to store code in a variable, and you'll avoid a lot of the word splitting issues.

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking at in the post from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to execute the command that is stored in variable with 
`eval "$updateSubProject"`

so remove the double & from varable and go for:
`cd project-dir && eval "$updateSubProject"`

Comment: Can result in significant quoting hell.